# Elasticsearch multi search api is not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch

Im using elasticsearch 8.3.2. Im facing the below issue while using multi search api.

**API:** https://elasticrunningserver:9200/myindex/_msearch

**Payload:**

```
 { }
{"query" : {"match" : { "message": "this is a test"}}}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "key [query] is not supported in the metadata section"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "key [query] is not supported in the metadata section"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a metadata section for each query

```
{ }
{"query" : {"match" : { "message": "this is a test"}}}
{ }
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its working fine as expected.
But another scenario, Im using Java High level rest client version 7.17.5. Im applying the same but it doesnt work. Please help me the proper syntax format for multisearch request on Java High level rest client.

Comment: SearchSourceBuilder mtS = new SearchSourceBuilder();
SearchRequest mtSr = new SearchRequest().source(mtS).indices(idx);
SearchSourceBuilder bld = new SearchSourceBuilder().size(10);
bld.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
SearchRequest blSr = new SearchRequest().source(bld).indices(idx);

MultiSearchRequest mlt = new MultiSearchRequest().add(mtSr).add(blSr);

MultiSearchResponse mltr = null;
try {
mltr = cli.msearch(mlt, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
} catch (Exception e) {}

Comment: This question being solved, you should create a new one and add the code to it so it's more legible for anyone to read. thank you

Comment: hi @Val, please find the detail link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73112314/java-high-level-rest-client-mutli-search-api-not-working-with-elasticsearch-8