# Java High Level Rest Client - Mutli Search API Not working with Elasticsearch 8.3.2

Tags: elasticsearch

Im using Java High level rest client version 7.17.5. Im applying the same but it doesnt work. Please find the below code

```
SearchSourceBuilder metaDataSearch = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest metaSearch = new org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest().source(metaDataSearch).indices(indexName);

SearchSourceBuilder keywordExactRequestBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder().size(10);
keywordExactRequestBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest keywordExactRequestSearch = new org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest().source(keywordExactRequestBuilder).indices(indexName);

MultiSearchRequest multiSearchRequest = new MultiSearchRequest()
                .add(metaSearch)
                .add(keywordExactRequestSearch);

MultiSearchResponse multiSearchResponse = null;
        try {
            multiSearchResponse = elasticClient.msearch(multiSearchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Im facing the below exception

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=key [types] is not supported in the metadata section]]
.......
Caused by: 
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=key [types] is not supported in the metadata section]]
......
```

Im enabled API compatibility mode. Im using elasticsearch version 8.3.2

Thanks